# Can anyone identify this project please?

Tags: aircraft-identification

This is a large photo of what looks like a model, with an Armstrong Whitworth stamp on the back.  Any ideas please?
[image]

Answer (score 8):

It appears to be a model of the Armstrong Whitworth A. W. 169. There is a good discussion at [secretprojects.co.uk](https://www.secretprojects.co.uk/threads/armstrong-whitworth-aw-169-f155t-contender.4464/) where they discuss the offset cockpits for the pilot and radar operator, including why the RO's cockpit is blacked out.

Comment: Ma\ny thanks indeed.